# How to make 100 thousand HTTP calls while maintaining the max connection

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, semaphore

Here I'm trying to make a call to an api after reading the csv. During the process, I want to restrict the number of connections. However, when I added `BoundedSemaphore`, we started getting `AttributeError: __aexit__ exception`

Sharing the code

```
file_name = "xgb_tmp"

RAW_FILE = f'/input/{file_name}.csv'
RESPONSE_FILE = f'/output/{file_name}.csv'
LOGFILE_PATH = f'/logs/{file_name}.log'
MAX_CONNECTIONS = 1000
POOL_SEMAPHORE = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=MAX_CONNECTIONS)


BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8999" # for local


async def fetch(session, url, data, headers):
    try:
        async with session.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, timeout=10) as response:
            return (response.status, await response.json())
    except Exception as e:
        return ("", {"error": str(e), "data": data})


async def write_result(data, writer):
    async with asyncio.Lock():       
        writer.writerow({"data": data})

async def inititate_api_call(session, data, writer):
    async with POOL_SEMAPHORE:
        url = BASE_URL + "/v3/xxx"
        data = {
            "a": data["a"],
        }
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }

        status, response_data = await fetch(session, url, data, headers)
        await write_result(data, writer)


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with open(RAW_FILE, 'r') as csv_in, open(RESPONSE_FILE, 'a') as csv_out:
            fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()

            reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
            aws = [asyncio.ensure_future(inititate_api_call(session, data, writer)) for data in reader]

            await asyncio.gather(*aws)
            print("Completed!!!!!")


# read csv and initiate migration
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
    print("total time taken: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `threading` module is not asyncio-aware and as such `threading.BoundedSemaphore` can't be used as an asynchronous context manager. In general you can't mix `asyncio` and `threading` classes. You want to use [asyncio.BoundedSemaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.BoundedSemaphore) instead.

The catch, though, is that `BoundedSemaphore` is bound to a loop. For Python versions up to 3.9 you can pass this in at instantiation time.

```
sem = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(value=1, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
```

Starting in Python 3.10, however, there won't be a `loop` parameter anymore. You'll need a running loop to instantiate your semaphore. You can accomplish this with your code by doing so inside `main` and passing it to `initiate_api_call`.

```
async def inititate_api_call(sem: asyncio.Semaphore, session, data, writer):
    async with sem:
        url = BASE_URL + "/v3/xxx"
        data = {
            "a": data["a"],
        }
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }

        status, response_data = await fetch(session, url, data, headers)
        await write_result(data, writer)


async def main():
    sem = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(value=MAX_CONNECTIONS)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with open(RAW_FILE, 'r') as csv_in, open(RESPONSE_FILE, 'a') as csv_out:
            fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()

            reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
            aws = [inititate_api_call(sem, session, data, writer) for data in reader]

            await asyncio.gather(*aws)
            print("Completed!!!!!")


# read csv and initiate migration
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("total time taken: ", time.time() - start_time)
```